# Qt multiple key combo event

Tags: c++, qt, events, key

I'm using Qt 4.6 and I'd like to react to multi-key combos (e.g. Key_Q+Key_W) that are being held down. So when you hold down a key combo, the event should be called all the time, just the same way as it works with single key events. I tried to use QShortcuts and enable autorepeat for them, but that didn't work:

```
keyCombos_.push_back(new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_W, Qt::Key_D), this));
connect(keyCombos_[0], SIGNAL(activated()), SLOT(keySequenceEvent_WD()));
setShortcutAutoRepeat(keyCombos_[0]->id(), true);
```

When using this approach I also have the problem that I can't catch single Key_W (or whatever the first Key in the keysequence is) strokes anymore.

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 6):

You can add a pressed key to the set of pressed keys and remove from this set when the key is released. So you can add the pressed key to a `QSet` which is a class member :

```
QSet<int> pressedKeys;
```

You can catch the key events in an event filter :

```
bool MyWidget::eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event)
{

    if ( event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress ) {

        pressedKeys += ((QKeyEvent*)event)->key();

        if ( pressedKeys.contains(Qt::Key_D) && pressedKeys.contains(Qt::Key_W) )
        {
            // D and W are pressed
        }

    }
    else if ( event->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease )
    {

        pressedKeys -= ((QKeyEvent*)event)->key();
    }


    return false;
}
```

Don't forget to install the event filter in the constructor:

```
this->installEventFilter(this);
```

Answer (score 5):

QShortcut does not support the functionality you're looking for. You can only make combinations with *modifier keys* like Shift, Ctrl, Alt and Meta.

What your code does is to make a shortcut that responds when the user first presses W and then D. This is also why it will conflict with other shortcuts that respond to just W.

When you want to do something when both W and D are pressed *at the same time*, you'll have to override QWidget's [keyPressEvent](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) and [keyReleaseEvent](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qwidget.html#keyReleaseEvent) methods in order to keep track of their pressed state, and manually call your handler function once they are both pressed. If you don't have a suitable QWidget subclass in use you'd either have to introduce it, or install an event filter in the right place using [QObject::installEventFilter](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qobject.html#installEventFilter), possibly on your application object if it's supposed to be a global shortcut.