# How to create QKeySequence like "Fn" + Key_Up

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard-shortcuts

As i understood from Qt documentation (`QKeySequence`, `Qt` global namespace), i can't use notebook `Fn` key as shortcut modifier.
The only modifiers Qt knows are: `Shift`, `Control`, `Alt`, `Meta`. But no `Fn`!
But may be some hacky way exists? like specifying `Fn` code directly.

Code:

```
m_actionGoToFirstPage->setShortcut( QKeySequence( Qt::Key_Up /*| Qt::Fn ???*/ ) );
```

Comment: Fn is highly specific to the keyboard and often not possible to read or simulate.

Comment: So you are thinking that the mission is impossible in the my case?

Comment: Whatever you're ultimately trying to do might be possible, but I doubt it would be with Qt. How easy it is otherwise depends on whether the manufacturer intended for you to be able to use the key programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first the `Fn` key is not a classic modifier key. (Chris said this already.)

## Some context

If a classic modifier key (`Shift`, `Control`, `Alt`, `Meta`) is pressed, the keyboard send a key code.
The OS handles this key-code and give it to the relevant applications.

The `Fn` key is special. Some manufactures handle it on the keyboard micro controller, this is described bellow. And some other send a classic key-code for the `Fn` key.

#### System handle the `Fn` key on the keyboard micro controller

If the system handle the `Fn` key on the keyboard micro controller:

You can assume that the keyboard has internal something like a translation table between the keys and the key codes. And if the `Fn` key is hold the keyboard uses another translation table. Some keys have the same key codes, some other keys have another key code. (This is extremely simplified model of the reality, but for this example it works.)

## Solutions

Since the manufactures implement the `Fn` key not all in the same way, there is no simple solutions that work on all keyboards.
I think it should be possible to combine the following small-solutions, to one big. But I will not work this fully out and I think it is not really fancy.

#### `Fn` key is handled on the keyboard micro controller

***If the `Fn` key is handled on the keyboard micro controller:***
Handle the Key code that the keyboard gives back. For Example my keyboard send on `Fn` + `F1` the `VolumeMute` key code. This does only work if there are differences between the two tables, explained above.

If your solution must not work an all devices, you can simply try what Qt Key is emitted by what Key Combination. On my system for example the combination `Fn` + `F1` is this Qt-Key: `Qt::Key_VolumeMute`.

It is also possible to ask the user on first start to press this combination and save the Key Code. ( [QWidget::keyPressEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) in combination with [QKeyEvent::key](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qkeyevent.html#key) )

#### `Fn` is a classic key

***If `Fn` is a classic key:***
Look up which Qt-Key is your `Fn` key. (I am not sure about this, but I think the `Fn` key is `Qt::Key_F32`. But you need to check up this. It is possible that some keyboards return another key-code.)
And then do something like this: [Qt multiple key combo event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081091/qt-multiple-key-combo-event).

#### Driver based

Theoretically: Some keyboards could be asked if the `Fn` key is actually pressed. (On Linux systems this should be something like `/proc/acpi/ibm/` or `/sys/devices/platform/`. But this is very driver dependent.)

Comment: So, the brief answer is "no, you can't" :) thanks for such detail explanation!